# Anime/cartoon where teens fight alongside creatures coming out of artifacts

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I sadly don't remember much, but I think it aired about 2006-2010.

I remember the main character had a creature by his side which had wings and I think one eye, and it was a greyish color.

They fought against some organisation and the creatures came out of artifacts, I think, but I could be wrong.

It was a group of teens/kids with one middle-aged dude with red hair.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***[Huntik: Secrets and Seekers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1696969/)*** (2009–2012)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik:_Secrets_%26_Seekers):

> *Huntik: Secrets & Seekers* is an Italian animated television series created by Iginio Straffi, the creator of *Winx Club*. It was produced by Rainbow, a studio co-owned by Straffi and Viacom. The series is about four adventurers who are part of a group called the Huntik Foundation. The Huntik team is led by their top operative Dante Vale. Every episode takes place in a different historical city and features magical elements inspired by European mythology. The characters are designed in a style that combines Japanese anime with Western animation.

> The series follows Lok Lambert as he uncovers the secret legacy of his missing father. His father, Eathon, was a member of the Huntik Foundation and a part of a secret world of **magic users known as Seekers and creatures known as Titans.** On his mission to uncover what happened to his father, Lok is joined by Dante Vale, Sophie Casterwill, Zhalia Moon, and **a talking Titan called Cherit**.

Definitely features an older, red-haired guy with some kids, and [Cherit](https://Cherit) roughly fits your description of a greyish creature with wings.